# Java Swing GUI. Activating/Firing more buttons while keeping the mousebutton pressed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

If I want to do an action, if a button is pressed I can use a ActionListener. But now if I want to activate more buttons by keeping the mousebutton pressed.
How can I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Subscribe the buttons to the `MouseOver` event (or something like that). If the event fires and the mouse button is down, then do your logic.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `ChangeListener` to the buttons `ButtonModel`, monitor for a change to the `isPressed` state.

The trick then is setting up some process which can then add the other components, in this simple example, I've used a Swing `Timer`, which will add roughly 40 new components a second while the button is pressed

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Timer timer = new Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            add(new JButton("..."));
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });

    public TestPane() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Help");
        btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
                if (model.isPressed()) {
                    timer.start();
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        add(btn);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

> Thanks, this works if I press one Button. But if I press one Button and move the mouse with pressed mousebutton to another Button the secound button does nothing

Just so we're clear, I think this is a bad user experience, but that's me

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private boolean pressed = false;

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            add(makeButton("1"));
            add(makeButton("2"));
        }

        protected JButton makeButton(String text) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(text);
            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    pressed = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    pressed = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (pressed) {
                        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getComponent();
                        System.out.println("Entered " + btn.getText());
                        btn.doClick();
                    }
                }

            };
            btn.addMouseListener(ma);
            btn.addMouseMotionListener(ma);
            return btn;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if I press one Button. But if I press one Button and move the mouse with pressed mousebutton to another Button the secound button does nothing

Comment: OP doesn't want to create new buttons but do a *drag* which fires any button he moves over.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès *"pressed I can use a ActionListener. But now ich want to activate more buttons by keeping the mousebutton presse"* Forgive me if the question is unclear

Comment: I think that's it! @MadProgrammer unclear questions => different interpretations, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

@npinti Now I can do an action for every button over which i hover with my mouse. But if I try to change the implementation, so that the action are only done, if the mouse is also clicked, the action only works if i press a button and over the same button again. `JButton b = new JButton(); 
        if(a==1){
            b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }else{
            b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 ) {
            matrix.activate(x,y);
        }
        });

```
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
           int pressed =0;
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                pressed =0;

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                pressed =1;

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {


            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getComponent().equals(b) && pressed ==1){
                    b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                }

            }
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                pressed =1;

            }
        });`
```

Comment: Based on this example, only the original button which was clicked would know when it's pressed

Answer (score 0):

Catch `mouseEntered` on your buttons and if a global boolean `pressed` is true (set it to true when you press a mouse button and false on release), fire an action with `JButton.doClick()` which *simulates* a click event on the button.

Comment: But how do I implement the global click check?

Comment: Choose how you want to start the click check. On press over a button? At any position just by pressing the mouse?...

Comment: Add `b.doClick()` in your own `mouseEntered` method.